Python @overload using union types causes overlapped function signature errors
I would like to write the following overloaded Python function:
from typing import Any, TypeVar, overload

_T1 = TypeVar('_T1')
_T2 = TypeVar('_T2')
_T3 = TypeVar('_T3')


@overload
def parse_as(ty: type[_T1] | type[_T2], s: bytes) -> _T1 | _T2:
    ...


@overload
def parse_as(ty: type[_T1] | type[_T2] | type[_T3], s: bytes) -> _T1 | _T2 | _T3:
    ...


def parse_as(ty: Any, s: bytes) -> Any:
    raise NotImplementedError()

The goal of parse_as() is to attempt to parse the input bytes as the given types and, if successful, return a value of the given types. However this gives the following mypy error:
error: Overloaded function signature 2 will never be matched: signature 1's parameter type(s) are the same or broader

Is there any way to express the type of parse_as()?
Aside: in my particular case all the TypeVars share the same class as their bound, if that matters.

Did you mean to use _T3 in the second one? You've used _T2 twice.

(and either way, what are these unions doing there? It's just def parse_as(ty: type[_T1], s: bytes) -> _T1, union is distributive over type, type[X] | type[Y] is equivalent to type[X | Y] and so several typevars make very little sense here)

Are you expecting to be able to write parse_as(int | str, b"..."), and have it return either an int or a str?

I fixed the _T3 problem mentioned above since the error will be the same even after the fix (in other words, I suppose it isn't a problem in your actual code). If what chepner said in the previous comment is correct, this question is a duplicate of How do I type hint a variable whose value is itself a type hint?. If this is not the case, please [edit] to provide more information on how you intend to use parse_as().
